# Does filter_var guarantee that $_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"] will be protected against XSS Injection?

Tags: php, xss

```
############################################
## Connection Creation for Both Databases ##
############################################

//Create Connection for Pokemon Test Database
$PokemonConnection=mysqli_connect("URL","username","password","database");

//Check Pokemon Test Database Connection for Errors
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

//Create Connection for Xenforo Forum Database
$XenConnection=mysqli_connect("URL","username","password","database");

//Check Xenforo Forum Database Connection for Errors
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

############################################
###Password Protection for Initialization###
############################################

//Sanitize Password Passed From xenForo and Redirect If Invalid ID

$Password = filter_var($_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"], FILTER_SANITIZE_ENCODED, FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);

if($Password != 'Password')
{
    header("Location: http://www.url.com/error.html");
    echo 'Invalid String Length';
    exit;
}
```

This is my code that begins the initialization of my script and my concerns are that I may not be adequately protected against injection should I choose to continue with my current implementation of this script.

I have read that variable filtering works to prevent this but I have also seen examples where that can be ignored and syntax can be used in the URL to exploit the script if using QUERY_STRING.

Comment: Are there any methods that can be done that allow a user to pull a string from the URL and protect against injection using that string? Because later on in another abridged script I do this same method and write to a database.

Comment: `$PokemonConnection` lol, `try { } gottacatchemall { }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to sanitize a string for sql injection you have to escape its special characters.

Use `mysqli_real_escape_string()` or more basically `addslashes()`.

To sanitize a string against XSS, use `htmlentities()`

Though you shouldn't have to sanitize the password, just have your database password hashed, hash this one the same way, and compare them.
You should not be showing this client side, so no need to sanitize it against XSS.

Comment: So, pulling something as simple as a 14 Digit Random Key from the URL and using it for queries comparison would be protected if doing the above functions would be safe?

http://www.url.com/php.php?1j4jtjdj3jj

Comment: Because, later on in another script I actually write that value to a MEDIUMTEXT column value in a MySQL database.

Comment: Yes, with addslashes and htmlentities it is safe.